"You have a version of `bitsandbytes` that is not compatible with 4bit inference and training"
I am now trying to finetune a llama3 model.
I am using unsloth,
from unsloth import FastLanguageModel

Then I load Llama3 model.
model, tokenizer = FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained(
    model_name = "unsloth/llama-3-8b-bnb-4bit",
    max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
    dtype = None,
    load_in_4bit = True,
)

I am running my script on CS Code, and my python and script are on WSL. My system info is as below:
==((====))==  Unsloth: Fast Llama patching release 2024.5
   \\   /|    GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090. Max memory: 23.988 GB. Platform = Linux.
O^O/ \_/ \    Pytorch: 2.1.0+cu121. CUDA = 8.9. CUDA Toolkit = 12.1.
\        /    Bfloat16 = TRUE. Xformers = 0.0.22.post7. FA = False.
 "-____-"     Free Apache license: http://github.com/unslothai/unsloth

Now I run into this error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[4], line 2
      1 # 2. Load Llama3 model
----> 2 model, tokenizer = FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained(
      3     model_name = "unsloth/llama-3-8b-bnb-4bit",
      4     max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
      5     dtype = None,
      6     load_in_4bit = True,
      7 )

File ~/miniconda/envs/llama3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/unsloth/models/loader.py:142, in FastLanguageModel.from_pretrained(model_name, max_seq_length, dtype, load_in_4bit, token, device_map, rope_scaling, fix_tokenizer, trust_remote_code, use_gradient_checkpointing, resize_model_vocab, *args, **kwargs)
    139     tokenizer_name = None
    140 pass
--> 142 model, tokenizer = dispatch_model.from_pretrained(
    143     model_name     = model_name,
    144     max_seq_length = max_seq_length,
    145     dtype          = dtype,
    146     load_in_4bit   = load_in_4bit,
    147     token          = token,
    148     device_map     = device_map,
    149     rope_scaling   = rope_scaling,
    150     fix_tokenizer  = fix_tokenizer,
    151     model_patcher  = dispatch_model,
    152     tokenizer_name = tokenizer_name,
...
     96         "You have a version of `bitsandbytes` that is not compatible with 4bit inference and training"
     97         " make sure you have the latest version of `bitsandbytes` installed"
     98     )

ValueError: Some modules are dispatched on the CPU or the disk. Make sure you have enough GPU RAM to fit the quantized model. If you want to dispatch the model on the CPU or the disk while keeping these modules in 32-bit, you need to set `load_in_8bit_fp32_cpu_offload=True` and pass a custom `device_map` to `from_pretrained`. Check https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main/en/main_classes/quantization#offload-between-cpu-and-gpu for more details.

`
Would anyone please help?

Have you looked at the surrounding code in the unsloth loader module to see how it's deciding that the installed bitsandbytes is missing the relevant capability?

Thank you Charles, i am following this script. https://mer.vin/2024/04/llama-3-fine-tune-with-custom-data/, it seems there isn't much around it.

What I was suggesting checking is https://github.com/unslothai/unsloth/blob/main/unsloth/models/loader.py. Mind, the version of unsloth on their main branch doesn't have the error message you quote in its source code at all anymore -- see how it's looking for transformers version 4.37 or later, and not looking at bitsandbytes at all.

So you might consider using a version of the unsloth bits new enough to have that updated logic, assuming that you do in fact meet its transformers-version check.

(that's assuming the ... in the transcript isn't dropping places where the code switches files, of course; you drop things from the question -- especially pertinent things like the identify of which module/file/library threw an exception -- and it reduces our ability to help)

(BTW, note that pip install bitsandbytes isn't asking for the latest bitsandbytes, it's just asking for some version of bitsandbytes, and can be satisfied by something you already have even if it's not current; use pip install --upgrade bitsandbytes to specify that you really want explicitly the latest version).

Thank you Charles for the replies. My Transformers is 4.41.2, and my unsloth is 2024.5, which is the latest. I did pip install -U bitsandbytes as well, all the requirements are already satisfied. My python is 3.9.

Please go back and edit the stack trace to  at least to add the content between where the filename for the last stack frame in the trace is shown and the end of the error overall. There's too much trimmed here to let us see where the bitsandbytes version check is being done: that is, we know the error is thrown on line 96 of some file, but we don't know which file with the question as presently given.

Again Charles thank you for the suggestion. I have put back some more context in the opening thread.

The additional context added in your last edit doesn't include replacing the trimmed part of the stack trace as was requested, so I still don't know which file it is where line 96 is the code actually throwing the exception. If I don't know that, I can't tell how it's trying to check the bitsandbytes version, and so can't distinguish whether the check itself is faulty (and if so how, or which library is responsible for the check so we can make sure it's current).

I just updated the thread again, sorry for the overlook. I just copied the entire stack from the output window.

Hmm -- the filename for the last frame is still missing. If you click on ... in the output window does it replace that with the omitted bits of the stack trace? Alternately, think about not using Jupyter Notebook and switching to a "real" Python REPL to get stack traces that haven't been cleaned up / munged by tools that are taking out important bits presumably to make them shorter / more readable.
